# Do all programming languages have syntax to end the whole program?

Tags: computer-science

I was thinking of a general interface problem and was asking myself if all programing languages have an indicator that shows the program has ended. Meaning, do all languages have a specific syntax in the source code that it is the last line of code.

This is a general computer science question.

It is a theoritical question.

Either they have it, because of convention or need, or it is optional.

Answer (score 0):

No, Javascript does not. Python does not. I'm sure there are others too.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot terminate a program with syntax in any highlevel language.